# How should multiple cholim be included in the refuah bracha in the silent amidah?

Tags: tefilla, choleh-sick

When praying for multiple cholim, how should they be included in the bracha of refaeinu? What words should be used in between their names?

For example, when adding another name do we insert ולחולה (with the appropriate final vowel for the gender of the sick person)?

Here's an example from the Koren siddur:

[image: Example from Koren siddur]

Comment: Sounds like you're working in the context of a specific formulation. Perhaps add it to the question? The 8th blessing of the Amida doesn't have a specific spot for adding in names (though of course names can be added on one's own like any other on-topic addition in the Amida)

Comment: According to some siddurim that show the inclusion in *Refa'ainu*, that is what is done. This is the way that I have been doing it. Note that the inclusions in the siddurim (such as Art Scroll) only use the singular.

Comment: Yes, the siddurim I have all have text for inserting a prayer for a single person but I was wondering how best to include multiple people.

Comment: I've added an image of the bracha from a Koren siddur showing the insertion to say a prayer for a sick person but only in the singular.